# Can I remove that horizontal 2x4 to install vanity?

Tags: vanity

I removed the mirror from behind my sink and found this hole. Can I take out that bottom horizontal 2x4 to make the cutout bigger and install a vanity without damaging the integrity of the wall? I believe it is loadbearing but it’s not obvious to me that the horizontal piece goes between two studs. If it makes a difference, the wall is the one that goes through the center of my split level home.

[image]

Comment: That picture is very small, so it's hard to see any detail. I'm willing to bet, though, that the horizontal piece is simply "blocking" added in so that something could be screwed to the wall at any location between the studs. In that case, you're perfectly fine in removing the blocking. Closer pictures of the opening would be helpful in determining this for certain.

Comment: I think you mean you want to install a recessed medicine chest?  Please clarify.  Also replace the picture with a larger and beter lit one, and I think maybe your next step should be to remove more drywall above and below this opening to see what else is going on there.  It's hard to see if the vertical part of the frame are studs or just a box built for the previous cabinet.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I'm going to open up the drywall some more and I'll get a new picture!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can squint out of that thumbnail image, the horizontal boards end at the studs. Therefore they're just a simple frame for the recessed cabinet I assume you removed. As long as you don't modify the studs substantially they can be eliminated.